# Running PSEXEC so files and directories are relative to target machine

Tags: ocx, psexec, regsvr32

Ok, I am having trouble registering OCX files on remote machines using psexec, but think I have figured out where my problem lies.

Basically I have a script that runs the following command

PSEXEC \WORKSTATION1 REGSVR32 /S "\WORKSTATION1\C$\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\CONTROL.OCX"

This successfully regsiters CONTROL.OCX and my application works... for administrators.

It does not work if a non administrator is logged on.

After hours of research and help on StackOverflow I have determined the reason is within the registry of the remote machine (WORKSTATION1) the location of the OCX file is stored in a string with the value of:

\WORKSTATION1\C$\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\CONTROL.OCX

instead of:

C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\CONTROL.OCX

Since normal users do not have access to the administrative share C$ they are unable to run the application that relies on the OCX.

Is there anyway to run REGSVR on the remote machine using PSEXEC and have the script treat C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32 as the directory on the remote machine instead of the machine I am running PSEXEC from?  That way the OCX would register with the proper path name.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`psexec` passes its arguments directly to the remote program.
Passing `C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\CONTROL.OCX` should work fine.

Comment: You my friend are absolutely correct.  Now I just feel silly.